¿Dónde podría obtener un JSON/XML/SQL que contenga todas las palabras ofensivas en español?
No es una pregunta troll ni nada parecido, lo pregunto seriamente. Estoy desarrollando un sistema de moderación para un proyecto y realmente necesito una colección de insultos/palabras inapropiadas/expresiones políticamente incorrectas para poder agregarlas a una blacklist y así censurarlas.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Seguro que existe, solo que aqui por como funciona el sitio, no damos esa informacion... probaste en google??

Eso es imposible porque hay palabras que pueden ser ofensivas en una región pero perfectamente válidas en otra. También depende del contexto en el que se use la palabra.
